# Mapping/connect to bad request issue on publishing Django website

Tags: python, django, mapping, hosting

Apologise but, I'm clueless on what to do.

My boss bought this Namecheap domain, setup web-app (example) "www.Monday.com"

Now he asks me to setup another web-app "www.Monday.com/ABC" with the Django framework.

I did the following instruction given by Namecheap: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10048/2182/how-to-work-with-python-app

and did the setup on Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

run ping check on DNS working

run this webpage www.Monday.com/IOT(exmple) result: 400

I open up the log and all I get:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.Moandy.com'. You may need to add 'www.Monday.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Bad Request: /IO/
```

The ALLOW-HOST in my Django setting is the same as the domain name they request, here is the code in my `setting.py` for ALLOW-HOT & DEBUG (I cover some part of IP address for security)

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['198.54.116.***', 'Monday.com/IOT','.Monday.com/IOT/accounts/login',] # domain name gose here
```

that lead me to the clueless predicament; I don't even know where I could map wrongly or even to start to debug mapping issue

If you could help I really appreciate it

Comment: can you post the exact `ALLOWED_HOSTS` as it is inside your `settings.py`?

Comment: First of thank you. I updated the question with allow host within the questions

Comment: Nice! Replace it with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['198.54.116.***', '.monday.com']` and let me know how did it go.

Comment: Hi Kostas Livieratos, sorry I late with the reply. I did what you told, nothing happens. I did try  Monday.com/IOT but this time I get 404 error

Comment: Alright. This is good news. 404 means that the page was not found, therefore you will need to check your urls.py file and the patterns in there. Otherwise the 400-error issue is gone, the host is now allowed to reach your server, even if the `/IOT` path is not found.

Comment: I'm sorry Kostas, maybe I not explaining very good enough. First of www.monday.com is in use by App1, my boss requires me to add another web-app, on the same domain_name, but add /IOT behind the domain_name. that leads me to believe it could be my django app